# Como colocar o valor de inputs do tipo date e time em um objeto Date

Tags: javascript, html, css

Alguém sabe como faço para puxar o valor do input data e time pelo botão e jogar o valor pra dentro do new Date() fazendo o contador regressivo pegar

```js
var to = new Date('2022-10-16 23:59');

function update() {
  var from = new Date();
  diff = to - from;
  if (diff > 0) {
    var dias = (Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24)),
      horas = (Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60) % 24),
      minutos = (Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60) % 60),
      segundos = (Math.floor(diff / 1000) % 60)
    document.querySelector('#dias').innerText = dias
    document.querySelector('#horas').innerText = horas
    document.querySelector('#minutos').innerText = minutos
    document.querySelector('#segundos').innerText = segundos
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval);
    document.querySelector('body').classList.add('alert')
  }
}
var interval = setInterval(update, 1000)
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #303841;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  color: #6441A5;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.count-wrapper {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  background: #f8f9fa;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 .6rem;
}

.meio {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 4rem;
  margin-top: 3%;
  color: #6441A5
}

.count-wrapper div {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: #6441A5
}

.count-wrapper span {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .2rem 0;
  background: #6441A5;
}

span {
  color: #f8f9fa;
}

.alert {
  animation: alert 1s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes alert {
  0% {
    backgrpund: #112
  }
  100% {
    background: #a11;
  }
}

input[type="time"] {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #6441A5;
  padding: 10px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 70%;
  left: 52%;
  font-family: 'Baloo Da 2';
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input[type="date"] {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #6441A5;
  padding: 10px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 70%;
  right: 48%;
  font-family: 'Baloo Da 2';
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

 ::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

button[type="submit"] {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #6441A5;
  font-family: 'Baloo Da 2';
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 67.7%;
  right: 40%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<h1>contagem regressiva para fechar edital </h1>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="count-wrapper">
    <div id="dias">00</div>
    <span>DIAS</span>
  </div>
  <div class="meio">:</div>
  <div class="count-wrapper">
    <div id="horas">00</div>
    <span>HORAS</span>
  </div>
  <div class="meio">:</div>
  <div class="count-wrapper">
    <div id="minutos">00</div>
    <span>MINUTOS</span>
  </div>
  <div class="meio">:</div>
  <div class="count-wrapper">
    <div id="segundos">00</div>
    <span>SEGUNDOS</span>
  </div>
</div>
<form id="my-form" method="post" action="#">
  <input type="date" name="inDate">
  <input type="time" name="inTime">
  <br><br>
  <button type="submit">Iniciar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você pode escutar o evento `submit` do formulário que é acionado quando clica no botão, capturar os valores dos inputs, concatenar num objeto `Date` e atualizar o valor da variável `to`

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var date = document.querySelector('input[name="inDate"]').value;
  var time = document.querySelector('input[name="inTime"]').value;
  to = new Date(date + ' ' + time);
});
```

Segue abaixo o fiddle com o código completo:

```js
var to = new Date('2022-10-16 23:59');

function update() {
  var from = new Date();
  diff = to - from;
  if (diff > 0) {
    var dias = (Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24)),
      horas = (Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60) % 24),
      minutos = (Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60) % 60),
      segundos = (Math.floor(diff / 1000) % 60)
    document.querySelector('#dias').innerText = dias
    document.querySelector('#horas').innerText = horas
    document.querySelector('#minutos').innerText = minutos
    document.querySelector('#segundos').innerText = segundos
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval);
    document.querySelector('body').classList.add('alert')
  }
}
interval = setInterval(update, 1000);

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var date = document.querySelector('input[name="inDate"]').value;
  var time = document.querySelector('input[name="inTime"]').value;
  to = new Date(date + ' ' + time);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #303841;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  color: #6441A5;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.count-wrapper {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  background: #f8f9fa;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 .6rem;
}

.meio {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 4rem;
  margin-top: 3%;
  color: #6441A5
}

.count-wrapper div {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: #6441A5
}

.count-wrapper span {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .2rem 0;
  background: #6441A5;
}

span {
  color: #f8f9fa;
}

.alert {
  animation: alert 1s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes alert {
  0% {
    backgrpund: #112
  }
  100% {
    background: #a11;
  }
}

input[type="time"] {
  background-color: #6441A5;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'Baloo Da 2';
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input[type="date"] {
  background-color: #6441A5;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'Baloo Da 2';
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

 ::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

button[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #6441A5;
  font-family: 'Baloo Da 2';
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 67.7%;
  right: 40%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 12px;
}

#my-form {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>contagem regressiva para fechar edital </h1>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="count-wrapper">
    <div id="dias">00</div>
    <span>DIAS</span>
  </div>
  <div class="meio">:</div>
  <div class="count-wrapper">
    <div id="horas">00</div>
    <span>HORAS</span>
  </div>
  <div class="meio">:</div>
  <div class="count-wrapper">
    <div id="minutos">00</div>
    <span>MINUTOS</span>
  </div>
  <div class="meio">:</div>
  <div class="count-wrapper">
    <div id="segundos">00</div>
    <span>SEGUNDOS</span>
  </div>
</div>

<form id="my-form" method="post" action="#">
  <input type="date" name="inDate">
  <input type="time" name="inTime">
  <button type="submit">Iniciar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, eu estava preso nisso alguns dias já 